# Ubuntu fails to detect my webcam more than once

Tags: dell, webcam, 20.04, inspiron

[image]

If I open/close cheese two times or more , Ubuntu fails to find the build-in webcam. Only after reboot the webcam will be functional for me and only once.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the cause of the problem, and many others reported the same frustration across the years.
As a workaround, to avoid rebooting, you could disable and enable the webcam.

```
$ sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo
    (sudo rmmod uvcvideo may work as well)
$ sudo modprobe uvcvideo
```

This worked for many since [old Ubuntus](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1036819&page=2) and [not-so-old ones](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528422/enabling-disabling-camera-from-terminal)

```
sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo
sudo modprobe uvcvideo
```

If `uvcvideo` is not the right module in 20.04, you can list possible values with [lsmod](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/lsmod.8.html):

```
sudo lsmod
```

Other sources:

https://digitizor.com/how-to-reload-ubuntu-linux-laptop-webcam-fix-without-restart/